# Why am I only getting one output value (and no debug output) from this code?

Tags: vb.net, debugging, loops, console-application

I'm just going to throw all my code in here in case there's something wrong with a piece of the code not in the "SelectName()" sub.

```
Module Module1
    Dim selectednames As String = ""
    Dim index As Short = 0
    Dim inarray As Boolean = False
    Dim amountofkeys As Short
    Dim namesarray() As String
    Dim names As String = ""
    Dim input As String = ""
    Dim totalnames As Short = 0
    Dim indexofcomma As Short = 0

    Sub Main()
        Console.Write("Howmany keys are there to be given away? ")
        amountOfKeys = CShort(Console.ReadLine())
        Start()
        While Not amountofkeys = -1
            SelectName(names, totalnames)
            amountofkeys = amountofkeys - 1
        End While
        Console.Write("The winners are: " & selectednames)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Sub SelectName(ByVal names As String, ByVal totalnames As Short)
        ReDim namesarray(totalnames - 1)
        If inarray = False Then
            For x = 0 To totalnames - 1
                indexofcomma = InStr(names, ",")
                namesarray(x) = Left(names, indexofcomma - 1)
                names = Mid(names, indexofcomma + 1, (Len(names)))
            Next
            inarray = True
        End If
        Randomize()
        index = Int(Rnd() * (totalnames - 1))
        For x = 0 To totalnames - 1
            Debug.Print("namesarray(" & x & ") = " & namesarray(x))
        Next
        selectednames &= namesarray(index) & " "
        movenames()
    End Sub

    Sub movenames()
        For x = index To totalnames - 1
            namesarray(index) = namesarray(index + 1)
        Next
        totalnames -= 1
    End Sub

    Sub Start()
        Console.WriteLine("Enter all the viewer's names, one by one.")
        Console.WriteLine("Once all names have been entered, press 0.")
        input = Console.ReadLine()
        While Not input = "0"
            names &= input & ","
            totalnames += 1
            input = Console.ReadLine()
        End While
    End Sub
End Module
```

Here's an image of what it does (I suppose you can see what went wrong)

13 inputs, 3 outputs expected, only 1 output given.
[image: Wrong output]

Any chance any of you can help me out in finding what's going wrong?

As from what I've figured out so far, it's doing the correct amount of loops etc. It's just as soon as it starts generating the "winner" for the 2nd game key it doesn't get a string value from namesarray.

Also, why is

```
For x = 0 To totalnames - 1
            Debug.Print("namesarray(" & x & ") = " & namesarray(x))
        Next
```

not giving me a debug output?

Comment: (somewhat offtopic) Is there a specific reason why you're storing a collection of names in one string delimited by commas?  Wouldn't it simplify things to create `Dim Names As New List(Of String)`?  -- I was looking at the actualy problem, but I was compelled to mention this.

Comment: Well, I'm still learning, which is why I always appreciate people looking beyond a problem to help me improve my code :) So thanks for pointing that out ^^

Comment: PS: off-topic my ass, replacing the array with a list(of string) fixed it all xD Thanks bro :)

Well, everything except for the Debug.print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify your problem.

Make names a List(Of String), and instead of adding ",name" to the string, use `names.Add(namereadfromconsole)`. Instead of looping though the names string, a simple names.Contains(thename) could replace `inArray` flag you're using. And instead of `movenames()` call, a simple `names.Remove(nametoremove)`.

As far as the Debug.Print() call not displaying anything, try checking, under Options->Debugging->General->[x] Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window.

Answer (score 1):

The main error lies here

```
    For x = index To totalnames - 1
        namesarray(index) = namesarray(index + 1)
    Next
```

I think you should do in this way

```
    For x = index To totalnames - 1
        namesarray(x) = namesarray(x + 1)
    Next
```

And keep in mind that the Random index will cause your code to crash if it will be equals to the maximum values in namesarray. (For example: `totalnames=6` and `index = Int(Rnd() * (totalnames - 1))` result in index=5, then movenames crashes)

The Debug.Print output goes to the immediate window or the output window, not to the console window opened by your code. Use Console.Writeline for that.